# Does jQuery .ajaxComplete() override other handlers?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to use [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) in one part of my project. I am wondering if it overrides any other AJAX request completion handlers?

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(completeCallback);
```

Comment: Well, you could test it...

Comment: This will add a complete callback to all requests set as global (true by default). Older complete callbacks aren't unbound. Now Karl 'asked' a good question: Why haven't you tested it???

Comment: What do u mean by override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX request completion handlers will run. The difference is that this global handler will run too.

So this is an event like any other. Multiple event handlers can sign up and they will all be run. Think of a `click` event, you can add several event handlers and they will not overwrite each other.

Answer (score 0):

It will be fired whenever ajax completes the request.

It is global handler so you attach it to document. It will not override.

If you want certain ajax requests not be global, you can do it by specifying `global:false`